# Compare datetime column with datetime variable in asp.net sql where clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime

I have a column named `compare_time`(datatype: `DateTime`) in database. Its value is inserted as `3/8/2017 12:09:08 AM`. Now in c# I want to write a query to compare if this column value is equal to Singapore's current date time.(Only need to compare the date.). Current Singapore date time is get as `08-03-2017 PM 03:35:11`.

```
  TimeZone time2 = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
  DateTime test = time2.ToUniversalTime(DateTime.Now);
  var singapore = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Singapore Standard Time");
  var singaporetime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(test, singapore);
  DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(singaporetime); //08-03-2017 PM 03:35:11.
  SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM time_details where compare_time='"+dt+"' ", con1);
```

Please help to correct the where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is to not compare the dates using automatic string conversion but use a parameter.
Still this is not enough because your DateTime variable contains also the time part as well the database column. So you need to isolate the date part both on the database data and in the variable

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(singaporetime); //08-03-2017 PM 03:35:11.
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM time_details 
                    where Convert('Date',compare_time) = @date", con1);
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dt.Date;
....
```

In this way you don't let the compiler decide which is the right string 'format' that is correct for Sql Server to understand your query.
Instead you pass the DateTime variable as a Date (using the Today property which doesn't have a meaningful time part) to the database engine that now has all the info to make the correct comparison.

Notice that this approach could not be the most efficient one. That CONVERT inside the WHERE clause could wreak havoc with your indexes. Probably you could use a different approach

```
string cmdText = @"SELECT * FROM time_details 
                   where compare_time >= @init AND 
                         compare_time < @end";

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdText, con1);
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@init", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dt.Date;
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@end", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dt.Date.AddDays(1);
```

Comment: shows : The version of SQL Server in use does not support datatype 'date'.

Comment: OK, change it to SqlDbType.DateTime. The important point is the value of the DateTime variable dt. If we use the Today property then the time part is just 00:00:00 and it should work well with the query that uses >=  and <

Comment: when using dt.Today shows :Error Member 'System.DateTime.Today.get' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead. I have changed it to dt.ToShortDateString(); Is it correct ?

Comment: Again my fault. Is dt.Date, and no you shouldn't use a string (ToShortDateString produces a string) to pass a datetime value

Comment: shows : Non-invocable member 'System.DateTime.Date' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: that was my mistake.used () at end of  dt.Date. Now corrected. working